# How to store and query a tree structure in Cosmos DB?

Tags: nosql, cosmos-db

I'm migrating a relational DB over to Cosmos DB and am unsure about a tree structure.
There are several thousand rows of data ("Offerings") where each offering can have child items arranged in a tree hierarchy.

In the source DB it's using the traditional `ParentID` tactic:

```
| ID | Content         | ParentID
|0   | "Root"          | -1
|1   | "Child 1"       | 0
|2   | "Child 2"       | 0
|3   | "Child's child" | 2
```

In my actual DB, "Content" is not just one field but multiple columns, some of them being JSON blobs already.

When moving over to Cosmos DB, I see three options:

**Option 1: Should I store the actual hierarchy?**

```json
{
  id : 0,
  content : "Root",
  children : [
    {
      id : 1,
      content : "Child 1",
      children : []
    },
    {
      id : 2,
      content : "Child 2",
      children : [
        {
          id : 3,
          content : "Child's child",
          children : []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This represents the actual structure and allows easy traversal of the hierarchy when reading it. However: what if I need (for example) "all children aged 10"? Is there a way to query for the property `age`, no matter how deep down in the hierachy and have it return a list of child object?

**Option 2: Should I store a list and an extra property representing the hierarchy?**

```json
{

  id : 0,
  content : "Root",
  descendants : [
    {
      id : 1,
      content : "Child 1",
    },
    {
      id : 2,
      content : "Child 2"
    },
    {
      id : 3,
      content : "Child's child",
    }
  ],
  hierarchy : {
    id : 0,
    children : [
      {
        id : 1,
        children : []
      },
      {
        id : 2,
        children : [
          {
            id : ,
            children : []
          }
        ]
      }

    ]

  }
}
```

This allows me to easily get all descendants without tree traversals. Is there a major pro/con for either one? Is either one bad design? Or does it entirely depend on what queries I mostly expect?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement a hierarchyId approach in Sqlite and really like it, it could be used in CosmosDB as well. Basically, a HierarchyId is a string field which stores the whole hierarchy in a simple format:

```
"/<root>/<parent>/.../<child>"
```

for example the child node 6 is child of 5 and the root is 1:

```
"/1/5/6"
```

Search is simple, for example all child nodes from 5:

```
STARTSWITH(c.hierarchyId, "/1/5/", false)
```

Or all the child nodes under the root 1:

```
STARTSWITH(c.hierarchyId, "/1/", false)
```

The only problem is like hierarchyId in SQL, you need to maintain the tree integrity, probably in the app side. So anyway, it is not the solution, but it is a solution.